# setChecked and setSelected in CheckBox not working

Tags: java, android, checkbox, interface

I have an Activity which has 5 fragments in pager. I used

```
 viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(fragmentList.size());
```

to be able to create all fragment in one time
I also have a listener which will pass parameter(object) to all fragment once I have a newIntent.

in one of my fragment I have CheckBox which should be selected according to the parameter from activity.
and other views which I were able to change the value of their texts and background.
just this check box I have set it on But when I see it, I have see it is off, all other events works well.

here is the activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_PopupOverlay);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_configurations);

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    setNdef(getIntent().getExtras());
    String type = getNdef().getString("id");

    List<Fragment> fragmentList = createFragments(type);
    SectionsPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    fillTableLayout(tabLayout, type);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(fragmentList.size());
    readNfcDialog = createReadDialog();
    writeNfcDialog = createWriteDialog();
    readNfcDialog.show();
    setForeground();
}

 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    super.onNewIntent(intent);

   
    ClassNfcTag wepTag = new ClassNfcTag(intent);
    String type = wepTag.defineClassTag();
    OmsRepeaterTag omsRepeaterTag = new OmsRepeaterTag(intent);
    byteMap = omsRepeaterTag.readTag();
   if (byteMap != null) {
   setTagOmsConfiguration(OmsConfiguration.fromByteArray(byteMap));
   for (OmsListener listener : onReceiveOmsList) {
        listener.gotOms(getInTagOmsConfiguration());
       }
   }
}
```

and here is one of the fragments

```
    @Override
public void gotOms(OmsConfiguration configuration) {
    setConfiguration(configuration);
    if (isAdded()) {
    boolean status = getConfiguration().getDeleteRsl();
    delete.setChecked(status);
    delete.setSelected(status);

    }
}
```

as a solution I have tried to use Switch instead of CheckBox and it worked well.

and I also tried to set the pager to start from exactly the fragment which has the CheckBox and it also work.

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(checkBoxFragmentPosition);
```

I also tried to debug the code and It shows me that the checkBox is checked and when I tried to change it to checked by touching it (programmatically it is checked, in UI I see it unchecked) it change itself from unchecked to unchecked  .and then with the next touch changed to checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, see below.

I had exactly this behavior of CheckBoxes. Indeed, one way to fix it was to switch from CheckBox to `com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial` aka ToggleButton.

But then I noticed the same behavior of a RadioButton in a RadioGroup. It was initailized to checked in my code, but in UI only its outline had a "checked" color, the fill (middle) was missing as if it was unchecked. The first click made it truly unchecked, the next one checked and then normal behavior.

**THE SOLUTION** was to move the call to `viewModel.setIsAllowed(..)` - that leads to a call to the observer of that field and ultimately calls `binding.myCheckBox.setChecked(isChecked)` - from `MyFragment.onViewCreated` to `MyFragment.onResume`. Same for my RadioButtons. After that, both CheckBoxes and RadioButtons are initialized correctly in UI: either unchecked or checked.

Answer (score 1):

just for the people who will read this question, simply this was an unresolved bug in android.
For my case I used an `toggleButton` instead `checkBox`.